# How to access a private variable which is within a function

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test{
    
public:
    
   int kk(int b){
         return a=b+5;
    }
    
private:
    
    int a;
   /*void priv()
   {
    int a;   // How to access a , if this part was not commented
   }*/
    
};

int main()
{
   Test  kris;
 
   cout<< kris.kk(5)<<endl;
    
   return 0;
}
```

I was trying to understand the concept of private and public members and the methods to access the private members when they are defined in a class. I wanted to rephrase the question to how to access a variable, which is local to a private function via an object of class "Test" (as defined in the code).

---

I found the answer to it and experimented it with my own code and i was able to execute the code. Below is the code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

class Test{
    
    public:
    int xyz_1(){
       
      return xyz_2() ;
    }
   
 
    private:
    int xyz_2(){
      int a=5;
      return a;
    }
   

};

int main()
{
    
   Test  kris;
   
   cout<< kris.xyz_1()<<endl<<"Sorry for the confusion"<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The variable `a` is local to the function only, so it cannot be accessed from outside the function. If you're asking something else, you should probably clarify that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: Looks like a classic XY problem to me. Please see  [Meta Stack Exchange – What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) first and then explain _what_ you want to achieve, not _how_ you're trying to do it.

Comment: I am new to C++ and one can already see it in my way of coding above.So, in C++, a private variable cannot be accessed if it is defined in a private function?

Comment: @krishna1950 The `private` member `a` and the _local variable_ `a` are two different, totally separate things. Again, explain what you are really wanting to do, not just how you are currently (and vaguely) _trying_ to do it.

Comment: @CiaPan: My question is short and explicit.

Comment: Not really. Do you mean if you did have a local `a`, how you could still access the member `a` instead? Then do `this->a`. But in reality, don't do that: don't shadow, and don't prefix `this->`. Just pick better variable names and be sure not to double them up.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. The `a` identifier inside the function _can NOT_ be accessed at all, except inside the function, because, as you were already told, it declares a _local variable_ which exists only during execution of that function. Outside the function it _does not exist_, so it can't be accessed. Whatever you do, it certainly does NOT require accessing `a` declared inside `priv()` from outside of `priv()`.

Comment: @closers: I hate it. I wirte an answer, and when I'm about to click 'Post your answer' the question appears closed. What am I supposed to do with my work now?

Answer (score 2):

> *How to access a private variable which is within a function*

You're trying to access a local variable of `priv()` in the function `kk()` which is impossible unless the visibility of the variable `a` is either public or outside the function (in case with classes) under `private:` (which will make it accessible to all member functions). In a rough way, you're trying to do something:

```
void fun1() {
    int a;
}
void fun2() {
    std::cout << a;
}
```

Which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to think more about your design and what you achieve.

Do you want to have a private member in the class to access the function? Then declare your variable "a" as a private member in your class, and use `this.a` inside your function. If you want a child class to be also able to access your private member, make the variable protected instead of private.

If you want to restrict any other function in your class from accessing that member, then I would be curious about what your intention is. If you try to hide the implementation you might want to look into the Pimpl technique. However, it also has a very specific use case (besides that you can use it to hide the implementation from developers, too).
[https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl[pimpl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl%5Bpimpl) programming technique][1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl)

If you add more information about your problem and intention I'm sure people can give you better directions.